# Selenium Webdriver(Java) - Application not proceeding

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There's a certain weird situation am facing in one of the pages  of my application am automating.

There's a button called "Next" ,which you click once you fill in some fields.

My code does that and clicks the "Next" button , but the application simply doesn't proceed further. It gets stuck displaying the 'loading symbol' forever.

However, when I fill the details and click on "Next" manually , am able to proceed further to the next page.

Anybody know what's going on here? Will be happy to provide more details.

Thanks,
footyluv

Comment: hi pavan kumar thats very strange, that should not happen but can you try a page refresh look may be it works after that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to :

1- Try to click on "Next" button without set your page data & check your page scenario.

2- If step 1 working fine it seems that you have issue in this page or security wise from your development.

3- you need to catch the event.fire that displayed your spinner and you need to make wait until it disappear like :

```
public void stepGeneralWait() {

        boolean breakIt = true;
        while (true) {
            breakIt = true;
            try {

                do{

                    Controller.driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
                    Thread.sleep(10);

                }
                while (breakIt);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getMessage().contains("element is not attached")) {
                    breakIt = false;
                }
            }
            if (breakIt) {
                break;
            }

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(12000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```